# C# - Check user input is already in array if true ask for another input

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I'm working on my project, but I got stuck.
Console Project!
Check user input is already in array if true ask for another input.

Comment: show your code, what have you tried.

Comment: string[] array = new string[4];
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array.Contains(input))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("duplicate");
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }

Comment: Edit the original post to add the code.

Comment: Please, edit you question to include the new code.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Also add comments to the code to show what you think it is doing at each step, and explain where you are stuck and what you have already tried.

Comment: You also need to mention that is homework, and the restrictions that go with it, because the obvious answer is to use a hashset

Answer (score 1):

It might be something like this, but you gotta do it  your own way because you did not post anything to show us how does it look right now..

```
int numberOfElementsInArray=100;
string [] array = new string[numberOfElementsInArray];
var input = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
{ if (array.Contains(input)) { Console.WriteLine("What you've enter is allready contained in this array"); } else { array[i] = Console.ReadLine(); }
```

Comment: And how can I make that, when I have an element in array, than ask for a new input but not jump to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You simple can try the old fashioned:

```
if (YourArray.Any(x => YourCondition)) {
    //Ask the user for another input.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
while (!InArray(Console.ReadLine()));
// ...
public static bool InArray(string s){
    foreach(var item in array) {
        if (item.Equals(s)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> allUserInputs = new List<String>();
int counter = 0;
int maxIterations = 100;
do
{
   counter++;
   String newInput = Console.Read();
   if (!allUserInputs.Contains(newInput))
       allUserInputs.Add(newInput);
   else
       Console.WriteLine("\nYour input already exists. Please try again.\n")
} while(counter <= maxIterations)
```

Comment: what is stopCriteria?